# .NET exception to throw for "xyz software not installed" or "required windows feature not installed/not detected"

Tags: c#, .net, exception, winapi, hresult

Just as the title states, I'm curious as to what .NET exception would best fit a scenario where a dependent piece of software (3rd party application, Windows optional feature/role, etc) -- not necessarily a dll dependency or library -- is confirmed as missing or can't be detected/determined for various reasons (permissions, etc).

- This scenario assumes that minimum system requirement checks have thus far passed (OS, architecture, environment, access rights, hardware, etc).
- `PlatformNotSupportedException` doesn't seem appropriate as it describes the *platform* as being part of the failure -- and this exception should be thrown prior to even arriving to code that checks "Is the required XYZ software/feature installed or not?".
- `FileNotFoundException` doesn't describe the situation accurately because checking file paths isn't always a reliable method of determining "Is XYZ software/feature installed or not?" -- install paths can change, uninstalled leftovers can be present/corrupt and produce a false positive evaluation of "File is present, therefore XYZ software is considered to be installed/registered", etc.
- `STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING (0x80073701`) The [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d) for this is "The referenced assembly is not installed on your system."

  - I haven't found much documentation on this error, but my interpretation is that this is usually witnessed specifically in the context of a failed Windows update/component/feature installation -- and not typically used in the scenario described in this question where the missing piece of software is a 3rd party application.

    - It *does*, however, seem to be a possible option when the missing piece of software is a Windows component/feature/role.
  - My efforts to find a resource that maps this to a .NET exception have come up empty.
- Throwing a [Win32Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=netframework-4.8) in .NET is an option, but so far I haven't found one that seems fitting.

Is creating a custom exception the best approach to this? This scenerio doesn't strike me as being an edge-case where a custom exception is the most common approach used in the wild, so I'm hoping that I'm just stupid and haven't yet found the best exception in the .NET API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.8) to use.

Comment: There is no point in trying to catch such an exception, so no point in using a custom exception type.  Simply throw Exception.

Comment: The exception I'm trying to find isn't so much for "catching" as it is for throwing, e.g. inside an if block.  I'm trying to use something a bit more specific than System.Exception, but that might be what I have to do.

Comment: @Paulπ I think the only ready-made .NET exceptions that may suit your situation are `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException`, but if that is not descriptive enough for your use-case then just make a custom one, ie `DependencyNotFoundException`, `FeatureNotSupportedException`, etc. That is what exceptions are good for. Be as specific as you can, so that you (or other users) can catch only what you/they are interested in.

Comment: I had considered using `NotSupportedException` on account of its name, but the description made me less confident that it would speak to "XYZ software/feature isn't installed":
`The exception that is thrown when an invoked method is not supported, or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that does not support the invoked functionality.`

The `NotImplementedException` appears to be for communicating that "this is unfinished code" -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-notimplementedexception#throw-the-exception